# Sass Invalid CSS Error: "expected expression"

Tags: css, sass

I've just been following the [Sass tutorial](http://sass-lang.com/tutorial.html). For some reason though the Sass file is not correctly generating the css. The terminal says the css is invalid but I'm pretty sure it's not. I've tried changing it too just in case there was a problem...

What have I done wrong?

Sass Version: Sass 3.1.10

Error message:

```
error sass/test.sass (Line 3: Invalid CSS after "80%": 
expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ";")
```

.sass file contents:

```
/* style.scss */
#navbar {
  width: 80%;
  height: 23px;
}
```

Comment: Ahaaa!

The problem was caused by using the wrong file extension!

It's **.scss** not **.sass**

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Based on your error message (`error sass/test.sass`) I can tell you're using the `.sass` extension for a Scss file. Change your file name to `style.scss`.

Sass and Scss use two different and incompatible syntaxes.

Answer (score 12):

Try *either*:

```
/* style.scss */
#navbar {
  width: 80%;
  height: 23px;
}
```

Or:

```
/* style.sass */
#navbar 
  width: 80%
  height: 23px
```

Note the difference in file extension and syntax.