# Can't precompile assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, asset-pipeline, precompile

I always pre-compile my assets locally before pushing to production, but this time I got stuck in an error I can't solve.

This is the error:

```
rake aborted!
Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "  background:": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "}"
(sass):2967
```

Problem is I have no idea which file is referring to.
I do I solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745855/sass-invalid-css-error-expected-expression

Comment: I don't think is a duplicate question as I don't have .sass files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always tricky when you have a big compiled file that comes from a bunch of small files.

I'd recommend using a linter to narrow down where the error is coming from

Try: https://github.com/brigade/scss-lint

Then you can simply run the linter and have it tell you where any problems are!

```
scss-lint app/assets/stylesheets/
```

This is also a good thing to work into your CI build, so you can catch problems as they come up

Comment: This is a good one! However, after running the gem I get a lot (tens) of mostly useless advices, like using downcase, etc. Can't really find the problem I'm looking for.. Is there a better way to find issues that blocks the file form being compiled?

Comment: Found the solution! For people who might have the same problem: run CSS Lint and then look for errors that start with "Syntax Error:". Thanks @DVG