# Attempting to declare SASS color variable and getting 'Invalid CSS'?

Tags: css, sass

I am attempting to use SASS for the first time on my next project (Pomodoro Clock). To get started I just wanted to declare my color variables and set a background color. When I try to apply the styling I get this error:

> Invalid CSS after "...(35, 61, 77, 1)": expected expression (e.g. 1px,
>   bold), was ";"

My code is below.

```
/*All variables declared*/
$japaneseIndigo: rgba(35, 61, 77, 1);
$babyPowder: rgba(255, 255, 250, 1);
$princetonOrange: rgba(254, 127, 45, 1);
$yankeesBlue: rgba(28, 48, 65, 1);
$mediumSpringGreen: rgba(24, 242, 178, 1);
/*Apply styles*/
*{
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
box-sizing: border-box; 
}
body {
  background-color: $yankeesBlue;
}
```

I know this is a super simple question that shouldn't need this forum to answer but I have sincerely Googled and asked for help elsewhere without any luck. Thank you for your help.

Comment: are you trying to csslint your sass? what is giving you that error?

Comment: To be honest I don't even know what csslint is. I am just running this in a CodePen at http://codepen.io/jrandall/pen/NbyVod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using sass or scss ? I dont think you are allowed to use ';' in .sass files.
Got it from here : [Sass Invalid CSS Error: "expected expression"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745855/sass-invalid-css-error-expected-expression?rq=1)
And double checked : http://sass-lang.com/guide

Comment: Oh my goodness. I had just done a simple CodeAcademy intro to SaSS and they use SaSS/SCSS interchangeably. In fact the whole "Learn SaSS" course is actually a "Learn SCSS" course. Thank you for your help

Comment: Ahah that got me a fair reputation in stackoverflow ;)

Comment: Also scss has become a lot more popular than sass over the years, but it is commonly called sass. So the confusion is not that surprising.

Answer (score 1):

In Codepen, change your preprocessor from Sass to SCSS.

See this for more info on the difference between Sass and SCSS:
[What's the difference between SCSS and Sass?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5654447/6008014)

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize there was any difference after doing a simple intro course of Codeacademy which is really poorly titled as "Learn SaSS". It seams like SaSS following Python-like conventions while SCSS is more similar to JS

Comment: SCSS Is SASS - with the same features. But SASS has a syntax that is quite a bit different from CSS. So, SCSS does SASS, with syntax very aligned to CSS, .. an, of course, the additional features.