# compiling sass to css with ruby

Tags: css, sass

I am new to sass and compiling sass to css with ruby is difficult so far. I have latest ruby and I have set the file watcher correctly too. Now the difficulty is that whatever i put into my sass file the css file with show error. the content of the files go something like the following.
the input of the file .sass.

```
      .content-navigation {
      border-color: #eee;   
      color: #ddd;
      }
```

the output in the css file

```
     /*
    Error: Invalid CSS after "#eee": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ";"
    on line 3 of sass/newsfeed.sass

 1: 
 2: .content-navigation {
 3:   border-color: #eee;   
 4:   color: #ddd;
 5: }

 Backtrace:
 sass/newsfeed.sass:3
 C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-
```

Comment: Have you tried this solution yet? https://stackoverflow.com/a/7746024/854246.  I'm closing the question for now; but if that's not the solution, feel free to `@` me and I'll reopen it.

Comment: looks like the problem I am facing. but how do I change the file extensions? @JosephMarikle

Comment: Presumably using the filesystem.  Based on the path, I assume you're on windows.  Open Explorer, navigate to where `sass/newsfeed.sass` is located, rename the file to `newsfeed.scss`, confirm that any imports are [correctly formed](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#import), and recompile.

Comment: Thanks @JosephMarikle

Comment: okay. I was confused if changing the file extension will make the ruby watcher confused. but luckily things seem to be working fine now. thanks

Comment: Glad to hear it. :)