# Sass invalid css error on compile in live sass compiler

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, sass

I just started writing sass and on my first lines

```
body{
    background-color: #272727;
    color: white;
}
```

I get an error of

```sh
--------------------
Change Detected...
index.sass
--------------------
Compilation Error
Error: Invalid CSS after "body{": expected "}", was "{"
        on line 1 of sass/c:\Users\user\desktop\Scripts\cryptoChess\src\Assets\Style\index.sass
>> body{ {

   -----^

--------------------
```

I am using the live sass compiler extension on vs code. Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using the .sass file extension for `index.sass` for a scss file. You need to change it to use the `scss` file extension for it to compile.

See also:

[Sass Invalid CSS Error: "expected expression"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745855/sass-invalid-css-error-expected-expression)